# sharepoint list displays items normally but after klicking it runs into item not found exeption

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, 2013, list-template

I have a normal SPList with some items in it. 
[image]

As you can see everything works fine. When I click on a list item, I run into an exception:
[image]

How is that possible?

edit:

I should mention, that this list was generated from another list (template)
The original list:
[image]

the template:
[image]

Comment: How did you create your list? Visual Studio? How it is deployed?

Comment: This list is made out of an existing one - from template. I add the items via visual studio - farm solution

Comment: Try to see if content type you are using exists in content type library. There should be something wrong with your Schema.xml of the list. If you do this with designer in VS try to see if all values (columns, content types) are well selected...

Comment: where do i find the schema.xml file, when the list is located at the server and not in my VS? I update the question.

Comment: Sorry but I never use SharePoint designer when work with SharePoint. I'll update your question and put more tags. Maybe others can help you